# Storing and Retrieving Values In Request Scope

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

I have made a jsp page for registering members, when registering if the person forgets to fill any field in the form , a error message is displayed in another page.

Inorder to achieve this i have used 3 servlets , First servlet to get the values from the jsp page and pass in to the second servlet which checks whether there are any fields empty , if yes , it returns back a message to the first servlet , which then passes the message to a third servlet to display the error message to the user.

My problem is the message doesn't get passed from first servlet to the third servlet. It just returns null.

Here is what i have done :

First Servlet Code :

```
        String firstName=request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName=request.getParameter("lastName");

        String userName=request.getParameter("userName");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");

   Message message=Authenticator.registerUser(firstName, lastName, userName,"Student", password);
   HttpSession mySession=request.getSession();
   RequestDispatcher failMessageDispatcher=                   request.getRequestDispatcher("/ErrorController");

   String message1=message.getMessage(); //gets the message to a variable
   request.setAttribute("message", message1);  // puts the variable in to the request scope 

   out.println(message1);
   if(message.getStatus().equals("0"))
   {

       failMessageDispatcher.forward(request, response); //forwards to the third servlet for displaying

   }
```

Third Servlet Code :

```
       String message= request.getParameter("message"); //get the message from the request scope
       out.println(message); //display the message
```

I know its a problem in the request scope, because if put it in to a session scope , it works, but the thing is i want to use the request scope for this job. How can i make this work?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why do you _want to use request scope_? That's not what it is meant for.

Comment: It's just that i don't want to create a session just to display error message.

Comment: Ok i have made a mistake. I did notice it now that i have used request.getParameter in the third servlet instead of request.getAttribute(), thats why it was returning null.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting null value because of in this case default value has come  of request scope.

In the case of request scope it does not exist when the response has send back.

whenever you click on any link then new request and response object is being created

once the response send back then the request and response is no longer valid or it is destroy

even it with click on same link.

request scope have the shortest duration .

when same request forwarded and include then the request scope make it sense otherwise it being destroy